# How do I find the highest pair(two dices) among n amount of dice. c code

Tags: c, c89

If I as an example role 5 dice with the values 2 4 4 5 2 the code will spit out "You scored: 4".

How do I get the highest pair among the dice?

Here is a part of the code.

```
void Pairs(int n, char* Lower_score1, int* dies)
{
  int i, j;

  printf("Pairs:\t");

  roll_multiple_dies(n, dies);
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for ( j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      if (dies[i] == dies[j] && j != i)
        Lower_score1[0] += dies[i] && dies[j];
    }
  }
  printf(" You scored: %d\n", Lower_score1[0]);
}
```

Comment: *with the values 2 4 4 5 2* - what are these values and how they result in `4`?

Comment: You can use two `for` loops and a six element array.

Comment: I am unsure about that, but if the dice ammount is under 6 and over 4 it will result in the score being 4 or 2. it is mostly 4 when there are two pairs and mostly two if there is only one pair.

Comment: I don't understand this. The title talks about a pair yet you only print one value. Makes no sense

Comment: I want the pair I get to become a score. if the dice show 2 3 4 4 5 I want it to take the fours like 4 + 4 = 8 and write it out in the last printf. like "You scored: 8" And if the dice show 2 2 4 5 5 I want it to take the highest pair and write out "You scored: 10"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `roll_multiple_dies(n, dies);` will fill an array with `n` rolls. Then do something like:

```
roll_multiple_dies(n, dies);
int cnt_arr[7] = { 0 };
for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
    ++cnt_arr[dies[i]];  // Count the number of times each roll result appear
}
```

Then check for the highest pair.

The "brute force" way:

```
if (cnt_arr[6] >= 2) puts("12");
else if (cnt_arr[5] >= 2) puts("10");
else ...
...
else if (cnt_arr[1] >= 2) puts("2");
else puts("No pairs found");
```

Comment: if you have time, can you answer why you use 7 elements in the array? And thanks for the help, it helped me move on to other problems in my program

Comment: @Radiset I expect the dice will roll the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. So I needed an array that could allow the index 6, i.e. `arr[6]`. Therefore the array must have 7 elements (where the element at index 0 is unused). An alternative approach: `int cnt_arr[6] = { 0 }; for(i=0; i<n; ++i) { ++cnt_arr[dies[i] - 1]; }` Here the array only have 6 elements so I subtract 1 when indexing the array.